# how to get mozilla like firebug console in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firebug, mozilla

the firebug console show each ajax request, and its parameters and the response,

is it possible to get this in chrome ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-I</kbd> will open Chrome development tools. I assume this is what you wanted.

To see Ajax requests, click on "Network" and you'll see all network requests being made. By default you see them all, although you can filter them and just see Ajax requests. Take a look at bottom part of Network tab; you'll see "Documents", "Stylesheets", etc. You want "XHR".

Comment: Nice short cut, didn't know that one :)

Comment: I know this, but where do you see all the events, ajax requests, responses

Comment: I always used Ctrl-Shift-J.. Is there any difference?

Comment: @Fnatte: the only difference I see is that using Ctrl-Shift-J, the console is automatically opened, while you have to manually open it when using Ctrl-Shift-I. Saves one keystroke. Important when you want to optimize your every move.

Answer (score 7):

Yea u can have it. Enable it from the setting of chrome console.

1. Press ctrl + shift + I
2. click on setting (Gear) icon at the bottom right.
3. check "Log XMLHttpRequests" at the console section part.

Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome developer tools will give you that and a lot more.  Click on the wrench and select Tools->Developer Tools.

I believe they were open sourced  by Apple - great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It's there by default click on the tool icon and under tools, can you find developingtool, which is a chrome version of firebug :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Firebug experience within chrome for the console, use Firebug Lite extension for Chrome.